# Help with my solution to an integral of Erf functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

I have been trying to solve this integral, but numerical evaluations between my solution and the integral do not match. Could someone please let me know where I went wrong?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^2)\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{Erf}\erf(bx)\erf(\sqrt{a}x)\mathrm dx,\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$$

I began with partial differentiation,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^2)\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{Erf}\erf(bx)\erf(\sqrt{a}x)\mathrm dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2x\exp\Big[-(a+b^2)x^{2}\Big]\erf(\sqrt{a}x)\mathrm dx$$

I was able to solve this integral, and checked it numerically:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2x\exp\Big[-(a+b^2)x^{2}\Big]\erf(\sqrt{a}x)\mathrm dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Bigg[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{(a+b^2)\sqrt{2a+b^2}}\Bigg]$$
In order to retrieve the original integral, I found the antiderivative wrt. $b$

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\frac{\sqrt{a}}{(a+b^2)\sqrt{2a+b^2}}\mathrm db = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi a}}\cdot\arctan\Bigg(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a+b^2}}\Bigg)+\mathcal{Q}(a)$$

Here, $\mathcal{Q}(a)$ is a random function. In order to solve for $\mathcal{Q}(a)$, I took limits:
$$\lim\limits_{b\to\infty^{+}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^2)\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{Erf}\erf(bx)\erf(\sqrt{a}x)\mathrm dx \longrightarrow 0$$
$$\lim\limits_{b\to\infty^{+}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi a}}\cdot\arctan\Bigg(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a+b^2}}\Bigg)\longrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}} = -\mathcal{Q}(a)$$

Thus, I'd surmise that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ax^2)\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{Erf}\erf(bx)\erf(\sqrt{a}x)\mathrm dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi a}}\cdot\arctan\Bigg(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a+b^2}}\Bigg) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$$

However, when I evaluate the integral numerically, it doesn't match with my closed-form solution. There must be something I did wrong after taking the partial derivative, but I can't figure out what. Please let me know your opinion!

Comment: Find $Q$ by setting $b=0$. The integrand vanishes leaving $Q=0$.

Comment: @Sal thank you, wow. Now the solution works. Is there perchance any explanation as to why setting b=0 gives the correct answer compared to b-> infty+?

Comment: [I think] For large $b$, it is not correct to replace $\operatorname{erf}(bx)$ with $1$ within the integrand. Even though *for fixed x*, we have  $\lim_{b \to \infty} \operatorname{erf}(bx)=1$, this is not true *uniformly* in $x$, and the range of integration ensures that we cannot regard $x$ as 'fixed' within the integrand. Within the integrand, for small $x$, we end up needing $\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{b \to \infty} \operatorname{erf}(bx)$, which is not necessarily $1$, since it depends on *how* those limits are taken.

Comment: @Sal that makes a lot of sense, I believe I've encountered such dilemmas before but it seems I failed to consider that implication this time around. Thanks once again for helping me out!

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: If you want to take $b \to \infty$, you can split the integral over $x$ up into $\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 dx \dots + \int\limits_0^\infty dx \dots$. In the first, replace $\operatorname{erf}(bx)\to 1$; in the second $\operatorname{erf}(bx)\to -1$. So we see the problem was that for large $b$, the sign of $x$ (which changes over the integral) is still important. *I think* we avoid any issues at $x=0$ here because the integrand vaishes at $x=0$

Comment: @Sal Ah, yes...Erf is an odd function. Now I just feel stupid xD.

Answer (score 1):

For **two** copies of $\operatorname{erf}$ I'm unsure if this has a closed form, but if $a=0$ or $b=0$ there is a [nice identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Integral_of_error_function_with_Gaussian_density_function)
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\operatorname{erf}(ax+b)\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\mathrm{d}x=\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{a\mu+b}{\sqrt{1+2a^2\sigma^2}}\right)$$

Comment: My attempt gives the closed form, except you must disregard the extra factor of $-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$